# CreateProcessAsUser not working with LogonUser token when printing from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, pinvoke, createprocessasuser

I am building a windows services under LocalSystem account that will print pdf in some time interval.

To do this I am creating user token by using `LogonUser`

```
IntPtr currentToken = IntPtr.Zero;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
bool loggedOn = LogonUser(user, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref currentToken);
```

and passing this `currentToken` in `CreateProcessAsUser`

```
CreateProcessAsUser(primaryToken, null, command, ref Security1, ref Security2, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpEnvironment, null, ref StartupInfo, out processInfo_);
```

But it's not doing it's job

If I get the current user token by using following code.

```
public static IntPtr GetCurrentUserToken()
{
    IntPtr currentToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

    int dwSessionId = 0;
    IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero;

    IntPtr pSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    int dwCount = 0;

    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, ref pSessionInfo, ref dwCount);

    Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

    Int32 current = (int)pSessionInfo;
    for (int i = 0; i < dwCount; i++)
    {
        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        if (WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive == si.State)
        {
            dwSessionId = si.SessionID;
            break;
        }

        current += dataSize;
    }

    WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);

    bool bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, out currentToken);
    if (bRet == false)
    {
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    bRet = DuplicateTokenEx(currentToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out primaryToken);
    if (bRet == false)
    {
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    return primaryToken;
}
```

Then `CreateProcessAsUser  works fine. But I need to create token by`LogonUser`because after user logoff`GetCurrentUserToken` method is not returning user token and I want user token also after logoff.

**Update**
I am checking last error after calling `CreateProcessAsUser` like this

```
uint exitCode; 

if (!GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo_.hProcess, out exitCode)) 
{ 
    int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); 
    Logger.LogService(" GetExitCodeProcess Error " + lastError); 
}
```

But GetExitCodeProcess returns true. I didn't found any error

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

As with the last time you posted this question ([Print Pdf from windows service and keep working after logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439184/print-pdf-from-windows-service-and-keep-working-after-logoff)), you need understand and workout what particular API call is failing and then call [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) which will give you more information about why the call is failing

> **GetLastError** : Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value

**Secondly**

It could be the case that one of the calls in `GetCurrentUserToken` e.g `WTSQueryUserToken` might just have a permission problem or something else that can be fixed (though i doubt it)

Reading the documentation for [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) it seems to state the following

> **WTSQueryUserToken** : Obtains the primary access token of the **logged-on user** specified by
> the session ID.

Further more, `WTSQueryUserToken` is probably returning

```
ERROR_NO_TOKEN
1008
```

> **ERROR_NO_TOKEN** : The token query is for a session in which no user is **logged-on**. This
> occurs, for example, when the session is in the idle state or
> SessionId is zero.

**Thirdly**

In my opinion, I don't think this approach is ever going to work in your situation and printing from a service is actually not recommended officially.

Please see the blow similar questions

[Printing from a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945177/printing-from-a-windows-service)

[Printing from a .NET Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990/printing-from-a-net-service)

**Lastly**

The only thing i can think of, is running you service under a User Account with access to the printers or impersonating a user by calling [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera), [`LoadUserProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-loaduserprofilea), and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser) then printing via Gdi+ (which is going have its own problems)

Please note

> While it is possible to send GDI+ output to a printer by obtaining a
> device context handle for the printer and then passing that handle to
> a GDI+ Graphics constructor, this is not recommended.  The GDI+
> functions and classes are not supported for use within a Windows
> service.  Attempting to use these functions and classes from a Windows
> service may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service
> performance and run-time exceptions or errors:

---

In short, you solution as it stands and the source code you currently have is unlikely to work, and in my opinion you are most likely going to spend a lot of time on this problem trying to do something services are really not designed to do (which is also out of the scope of the current question).

I really think you need to seriously reconsider what you are trying to do and why and wish you the best of luck

**Additional information on GDI Printing and printing from a service**

[How to install printer which should be accessible from windows service?](https://superuser.com/questions/737627/how-to-install-printer-which-should-be-accessible-from-windows-service)

[Printing from a Windows Service](http://Printing%20from%20a%20Windows%20Service)

Comment: I am check last error like this 
`uint exitCode;
            if (!GetExitCodeProcess(processInfo_.hProcess, out exitCode))
            {
                int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Logger.LogService(" GetExitCodeProcess Error " + lastError);
            }`
But `GetExitCodeProcess` returns `true`.
I didn't found any error

Answer (score 1):

Blatantly stolen from the linked pages.

Typically, the process that calls the [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) function must have the SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME.

The [LocalSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) account has the following privileges:
...
SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME (disabled)
So I am surprised that CreateProcessAsUser ever works in LocalSystem context.

CreateProcessAsUser does not load the specified user's profile into the HKEY_USERS registry key. Therefore, to access the information in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key, you must load the user's profile information into HKEY_USERS with the LoadUserProfile function before calling CreateProcessAsUser. Be sure to call UnloadUserProfile after the new process exits.

CreateProcessAsUser seems a bit more picky than CreateProcessWithLogonW. I would try [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx) with the LOGON_WITH_PROFILE parameter.

You call DuplicateTokenEx on the token in the code that seems to work.  You might want to try that with the LogonUser token.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any information about your printing process, but from what you provided, I guess it must need to be run under interactive session. Your first way didn't work because the token provede by `LogonUser` has same session id as the calling process which is 0. And your second way didn't work after log out is because `WTSQueryUserToken` will fail as it suppose to. So I suggest you try winlogon solution which could be summarized as find out winlogon process of interactive session, duplicate its token and use the token to create you printing process. [This acticle](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite) has all the details.